# Pea plants- slug damage or something I did?

Tags: fungus, rot, peas, slugs

Can slug damage cause the bottom of pea stalks to die? All the bottom leaves are going black and crispy and falling off. I’ve seen another post where it said root rot but the planter they are in has very good drainage and we haven’t over watered them so I am wondering if it’s the damage from slugs or something that I’m doing so I can learn for next year. Very new gardener clearly [image]